# Sort array by the distance to a number

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

For example if you have a set of numbers `5,4,3,2,1` and you want all numbers ordered by closest to 3 the result would be `3,2,4,5,1`.

I've tried using `uasort` and written a custom sort function to take the fixed digit(3 in this case), but it didn't work. I wrote the function to take the fixed digit away from the current two digits being compared and applied `abs` to them.

I need a way where I can compare which number of comparing how close the current number being accessed is and to slot it in the right place in the array.

Any ideas? Can this be achieved using `uasort`?

Comment: Would 4 not be closer than 1?

Comment: I don't understand your "closest to 3", could you please elaborate on it a little more?

Comment: 3,2,4,1,5 would be the same as 3,4,2,5,1 surely in a 'closeness' order

Comment: Sorry my mistake, amended!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`uasort()` is already a good start. Now you just have to use the distance to 3 as criteria to sort your array:

```
number   | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
---------------------------------------
distance | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
```

Code:

```
uasort($arr, function($a, $b){
    return abs(3-$a) - abs(3-$b);
});
```